# Responsive height

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

**This is my code:**

```css
#bener{
        background:url(../img/main.png) no-repeat;
     background-size:120%;
    }
    
    .bener_content{
        color:#fff;
     text-align:center;
     margin-top: 30%;
    } 
    .bener_overlay{
     background: rgba(75, 78, 78, 0.7);
        height: 120%; //This line
    } 
    .bener_content h2{
        color:#ffff;
    } 
    .bener_content p{
        color:#ffff; 
    }
```

```html
    
<section id="bener" class="">
   <div class="bener_overlay">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="bener_content">
           <p class="textmiddle">TEXT</p>
     <h3>Text</h3>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The problem I have is that whenever I try my website on a different resolution, my home page image doesn't scale, the width is fine, but the height is always the same. In the .benner_overlay I used height in percentage, but for some reasons it does nothing and when I use pixels, it is not responsive.
How can I solve this, so that wherever I try my website, the home image covers the whole screen?

Comment: _“In the .benner_overlay I used height in percentage, but for some reasons it does nothing”_ - CSS 101: A height in percentage only has an effect, if the parent element has an explicit height set as well.

Comment: The percentage value for width must be maximum 100%. This is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBroe already mentioned as a comment, in order to use percentage based heights your parent element needs to have a percentage based height as well. To achieve that you basically have to start at the root element and go through the tree. A possible solution could look like this.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#bener {
  background: url(../img/main.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 120%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vjoonftc/)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving height to your background image as:

```
height:100vh;
```

Then it will scale to the viewport height of any device.

Answer (score 0):

try using `height:5vh` or put you tag in another div called mydiv (or something else) and mydiv:`height: 5vh`